# ng serve issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, angular, ubuntu-16.04, angular-cli-v6

I've installed AngularCLI (Angular6) on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 with [regular](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) way. then I've tried to serve my app with

`ng serve --open`

But the terminal became as the screenshot below:

[image: the screenshot of the terminal:]

I want to know what is this error or issue about and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please explain how you installed the Angular CLI.

Comment: I installed as steps provided in https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: What happens when you execute `ng -v`?

Comment: this shows up: Mg++ version:
 Mg++ 1.5beta1 (formerly MicroGnuEmacs Adv.)

Comment: Not sure but it looks like the `ng` command is already registered to something else.

Comment: Problem solved! that wasn't for `ng` command, It was about @angular/core installation. I installed AngularCLI globally with `npm` and that wasn't the right way, I should install with  `sudo npm`  instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a permission problem. Just use `sudo` for superuser.

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

It's a package that has the same name and you need to remove it using the following command

```
    sudo apt remove mg ng-common
    npm install -g @angular/cli
```