# Installation of Angular failed in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, installation

I am aware that this problem has already been reported before in this forum, but none of the proposed solutions (at least the ones I understood) has worked for me, so I will explain my case in detail.

I could successfully install both NodeJs and Angular CLI, but once there it doesn't recognize the `ng` command.

It says the command `ng` was not found, but it can be installed with `sudo apt install ng-common`.
But when I do so, then each time I use `ng` it appairs something unexplainable for me:

[image]

From there I can only abort the process with `ctrl-z`.

An odd thing is that the first time I installed it, it allowed me to use `ng new` and create a project. But then this problem started when I tried `ng serve`. And from there I have never been able to use the `ng` command, even though I have uninstalled and installed programs as suggested by various forums. For example, I have already tried:

```
sudo apt remove ng-common
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

When I do that, the editor does not appear as in the image any more, but it returns to the state when `ng` is not recognized.

I have also tried:

```
sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and it didn't work either.

Those are the versions I have installed:

```
npm --version: 3.5.2
node --version: v8.10.0
+ @angular/cli@9.1.7
Visual Studio Code: 1.45.1
Chromium 83.0.4103.61 snap
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem for 16.04 LTS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603464/ng-serve-issue-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your path doesn't include the location of the global `node_modules` folder.

Try to find the install location of `@angular/cli` (possibly in */usr/local/lib/node_modules*).

To add this folder to the PATH environment variable, add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$PATH"
```

After a shell restart you should be able to issue the `ng` command. 
To know which `ng` are you using, issue the command:

```
which ng
```

Comment: Alessandro, I did it as you suggested, but it didn´t work. It still don't recognize the "ng" command.

Comment: Can you find the ng executable using something like `find / -executable -type f -name ng` (you may need sudo)? If there is a match, try running it using the complete path

Answer (score 0):

This seems an issue that can have several causes. In my case I could solve it by using alias:

```
alias ng="/home/mario/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```